# How to make RaphaelJS graph work with fluid layout

Tags: javascript, svg, raphael, fluid-layout, vml

Because of IE8, I use RaphaelJS to generate a graph that will be `SVG` in all modern browsers (e.g. Chrome, FireFox, Safari, IE9+) but will be `VML` in IE8.

This graph is embedded inside a `<div>`, which is part of a page using fluid layout. With pure `SVG`, I can use properties like `viewBox` and `preserveAspectRatio` to make it work, that is, the graph (and the elements within) scales up and down as the browser window resizes.

But how does it work with the `VML` case? Do I need to roll my own by re-drawing the whole graph  upon window resize event? Is there any method available from RaphaelJS to simplify this case?

Answer (score 0):

[Paper.setViewBox](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Paper.setViewBox) should handle this for VML as well as SVG AFAIK.

That said, I'm not sure how well VML handles fluid layouts.

Comment: when do I call `setViewBox`? I tried calling it after the graph is created, but when I resize the browser window, nothing happens - the graph stays the same size (note I am doing with a `SVG` graph in Chrome).

Answer (score 0):

For all good browsers you can set width/height in percents which will make image "fluid" automatically (it will resize with DIV container), for IE7-8 you should use custom resizing function which will do `paper.setViewBox()` manually:

```
  if($.browser.msie && $.browser.version < 9){
       R = Raphael('divID', 640, 480);
       $(window).on('resize', yourCustomfluidResizeFunction);
  }else{
       R = Raphael('divID', '100%', '100%');
  }
```